# I have messed up a remote repository, can I restore from a local that's ok?

Tags: git, repository, local, restore

I've messed up my remote repository, can I restore it?

Situation:

- laptop (pulled form repository where
  I pushed from another laptop with
  wrong data)
- desktop (which has a good
  local repository - yesterday)

desktop

```
gd@t4q:/var/www/html/t1.org$ git remote show origin
Enter passphrase for key '/home/gd/.ssh/id_rsa': 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@ip:t1_org.git
  Push  URL: git@ip:t1_org.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop tracked
    master  tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop merges with remote develop
    master  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop pushes to develop (local out of date)
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
```

On the desktop, develop is out of date, due information on the remote is different, but wrong.

Can I push local repository from my desktop to my git server?  Then reapply patches and pull everything back on my laptop?

If I do need to provide more information, please let me know.

TIA, 
Fossie

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "messed up". If you mean "obliterated", then by all means, push back there. If you mean "pushed a bad commit", then you may just be wanting to revert the commit. I imagine you're somewhere in between those two extremes?

Answer (score 0):

You can force an overwrite with `git push -f` from your local (good) repository.

Comment: If you are sharing this repo with anyone else this can cause big problems if they've pulled from your bad push. Changing the history of a central repo when others are pushing/pulling from it is not a good practice.

Comment: It 'can' cause problems but not irreconcilable ones (which is why I prefer `fetch` over `pull`. It is an option, however. And it is a valid choice in many cases.

Comment: Thx, I managed it already by moving the remote repository (in case something didn't work) and pushed it again from the good local repo, applied patches, pushed it, and finally pulled them on my laptop and everything seems to be good.